# "Under no obligation" usage

Tags: meaning-in-context

I`d be most appreciative if someone could explain me about this sentence.

> I am under no obligation to accept any referral or job to which I have been introduced by the Agency

I found the above sentence in an agreement letter and I am little bit confused in meaning. Does this sentence mean it is also okay if I don't accept the job which is introduced by the Agency??

Comment: In short, yes. Obligation means commitment. Google 'obligation meaning' and I think it will be clear to you. It is often used in formal documents. Have fun btw!

Comment: Fyi, explain something to someone: explain this sentence to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that no one is going to force you to accept any job or referral which you get via the agency.

Answer (score 1):

Idiomatically, you're [*under an obligation (to do X, say)*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/under-an-obligation) if there's an *obligation, need* for you to do X. Correspondingly, if you're *under **no** obligation to do X*, that means ***no such obligation exists***.

Simpler examples showing how using ***no X*** as a "noun phrase" primarily implying *X does not exist...*

> [*I serve no master*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I%20serve%20no%20master%22)
>    [*I want no sympathy*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I%20serve%20no%20master%22#tbm=bks&q=%22I%20want%20no%20sympathy%22)

...meaning *There is no master whom I serve, There is no sympathy which I want.*